# Python DataFrame String replace accidently Returing NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I encounter a weird problem in Python Pandas, while I read a excel and replace a character "k", the result gives me NaN for the rows without "K". see below image

[image]

It should return 173 on row #4，instead of NaN, but if I create a brand new excel, and type the same number. it will work.

or if i use this code,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'sales':['75.8K','6.9K','7K','6.9K','173','148']})
df
```

[image]

then it will works well. Why? please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['nums'] = df['sales'].astype(str)
df['nums'] = pd.to_numeric(df['nums'].str.replace('K', ''))
```

Comment: This solution only works on the sample dataset, doesn't work on my real dataset, but I still accept your answer. unknown bug in Python software

Comment: @PyBoss can you somehow provide your real dataset to me? so I would be able to help you more? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `173` and `148` values from the excel import are numbers, not strings. Since `str.replace` returns a value that is non-numeric, these values become `NaN`. You can see that demonstrated by setting up the dataframe with numbers in those position:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'sales':['75.8K','6.9K','7K','6.9K',173,148]})
df.dtypes
# sales    object
# dtype: object
df['num'] = df['sales'].str.replace('K','')
```

Output:

```
   sales   num
0  75.8K  75.8
1   6.9K   6.9
2     7K     7
3   6.9K   6.9
4    173   NaN
5    148   NaN
```

If you don't mind all your values being strings, you can use

```py
df = pd.read_excel('manual_import.xlsx', dtype=str)
```

or

```
df = pd.read_excel('manual_import.xlsx', converters={'sales':str})
```

should just convert all the `sales` values to strings.

Comment: I try to add converters={'sales': str} when i read it , still doesn't work, please help with solution

Comment: @PyBoss see my edit - but what you tried should have worked too...

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: @PyBoss well that is weird, it works fine on my computer with an excel file containing the data in your question. But this should solve the problem: `df['num'] = df['sales'].astype(str).replace('K','')`

Comment: other solution works on that sample dataset, doesn't work on my real dataset. it's unknown bug in Python software